# row change event of Datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on my college project in c#.
In which I have one datagridview which is connected to database and fetch all data form database when form gets load.
now my requirement is I want to update the current row data(slected row) in my sql table if I make any changes in any cells of tht row and that event(update data in sql) should be generated when I click new row of same datagridview.

please help me to write such code.

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building a layered application.

- presentation layer - handling the form, datagrid, events
- data access layer - accesses the database and adds/removes/updates entries upon receiving a command.

It is, however, big amount of code. If you want specific help I would need some code. Otherwise [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples) article is *very* helpful to understand the basics of data binding, listening for changes in a collection, etc.

If you need something simpler you could add a `RowChanged` event handler for your table:

```
  private static void Row_Changed(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // Execute some stored procedure for row updates here
    }
```

EDIT: Dennis is actually giving you a superb answer. If you don't understand the basics, refer to the article I have linked - it covers the topics mentioned in his answer and explains why you use what you use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do at least three things:

- use data binding;
- implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your data model;
- implement [`IEditableObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your data model.

Here's sample model:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject
{
    private bool isEditing;
    private bool isChanged;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private string name;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set
        {
            if (age != value)
            {
                age = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private int age;

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (isEditing)
        {
            isChanged = true;
        }
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEditableObject

    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        isEditing = true;
    }

    public void CancelEdit()
    {
        isEditing = false;
    }

    public void EndEdit()
    {
        if (isChanged)
        {
            // generate and execute update SQL here
        }
        isEditing = false;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and sample form code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingList<Person>
        {
            new Person { Name = "John", Age = 25 },
            new Person { Name = "Alice", Age = 32 },
            new Person { Name = "Peter", Age = 30 },
        };
    }
}
```